# Xamarin Oreo Adaptive Icons

Tags: xamarin.android, android-8.0-oreo

Did any of you successfully make use of the "Adaptive Icons" for xamarin android, introduced in Oreo?

I managed to make it work, if the .png images are placed in the Drawable-folders, but not if they are placed in the MipMap-folders.

I have followed the guidelines in this link, and it works when using Android Studio... weird I think?

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html

Comment: You want it to work when your images are in mipmap i suppose ?

Comment: I want to have the old launcher_icons in the mipmap folders, and then I have want to have the adaptive icon xml, like they have it in the link "res/mipmap-anydpi/ic_launcher.xml."... But doing this, shows the default launcher icon... The only fix I have found, is to place the ic_launcher.xml, in the drawble-v26 instead, and move the launcher_icons to the drawble folders as well, in order to refer to the images like "drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: Share some code then may be

Comment: Any updates? I am unable to get this working.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to [this blog post](http://www.magdalenadziesinska.pl/xamarin/adaptive-icon-in-xamarin-native-android-part-2/) I was able to use adaptive Icons in my Xamarin.Forms Android app.

Steps involved

1. Create an adaptive Icon using Android Studios [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#access) (note that it takes a while before you can actually add a new `Image Asset` in Android Studio as the editor is first initializing.)
2. Once the Launcher Item is created you can open the res directory in file explorer.
3. Copy all `mipmap-*`-folder into the Xamarin.Forms Android Project `Resources` directory.
4. Update the `AndroidManifest.xml` to contain the new `icon` and `roundIcon` asset

```
<application android:label="MyApp"
               android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
               android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
               android:appCategory="productivity"></application>
```

5. In the MainActivity also update the `Icon` and `RoundIcon` values

```
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", RoundIcon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
```

Comment: The blog post rates a 2 out of 5, but at least it something! Hey Xamarin, you want to provide a working example so people don't have to waste hours on some stupid icons? I found you do not want the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder or associated xml files. I am guessing the xml files are Xamarin icons in svg-like format and the anydpi folder actually takes precedence over the others!

Comment: I needed to add ic_launcher_background.xml and ic_launcher_foreground.xml from the drawable directory to get this to work.

Comment: For anyone finding this now, to make this work I had to manually add the mipmap folders to the .csproj file: `<AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-*\ic_launcher*"/>` (this will include the icons and the xml files from mipmap-anydpi-v26.) Since my icon uses a solid color background I also had to manually include `Resources\ic_launcher_background.xml`, and the anydpi may also need you to include xmls from drawable as well. (Visual Studio may do all of this automatically, I'm using JetBrains Rider.)

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly there is a bug in xamarin android mipmap folder that is well explained [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49320/mipmap-folders-issue) as well as in the [Release Notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/)

There are also some bugzilla reports :

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56146

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59904

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the post! But my issues is not that I cannot find the mipmap files, or that i get any build errors... The launcher icons i have in the mipmap folders, works fine. But there is an issue, when trying to use an adaptive-icon, located in "mipmap-anydpi-v26"

Comment: the mipmap folder in xamarin has a lot of bugs is what I wanted to point out, (been working on it for a year now!) Anyways Goodluck in case you find a solution feel free to tag me! Thanks.

Comment: sure thing :) Thanks. I will.